# How to start Jboss as 7 in command line

Tags: command-line, jboss

Hello I am new in Jboss as7. I plugged in the Jboss AS7 into eclipse, but the start button does not work properly. It shows `An internal error occurred during: "Starting JBoss 7.0 Runtime Server".java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Can I use the command window to start and stop the Jboss server?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The user guide is pretty clear on how to to this :)

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7UserGuide

I suggest you try the standalone mode first (from the guide above):

If you want to work in standalone mode, open a terminal and cd into the distribution's bin directory, and run the "standalone" launch script:

```
$ cd bin
$ ./standalone.sh
```

On Windows:

```
> cd bin
> standalone.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

In the windows, Before run JBoss server you should check your java version. It works only java version 7. You should keep server file in C: drive, it is easily to configure. then set the JBOSS_HOME path and set it in the path variables. after finished this path setting,go to the bin folder.type,

cd bin

standalone.bat

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `Windows` and your `JBOSS_HOME` environment variable is set you can also fire `standalone.bat` command directly from your command prompt to start your jboss server.